# Create an anchor with \DOMDocument

Tags: php, domdocument

How can I create an anchor with `\DOMDocument` ?

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$e = $dom->createElement('a', 'link text');
$a = $dom->createAttribute('href');
$a->value = 'http://google.com';
$dom->appendChild($e);

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Result is

```
<a>link text</a>
```

Attribute doesn't work :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$e = $dom->createElement('a', 'link text');
$a = $dom->appendChild($e);
$a->setAttribute('href', 'http://google.com');

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Result is

```
<a href="http://google.com">link text</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to set the attribute. With a `DOMAttr` already in hand this can be done with:

```
$e->setAttributeNode($a);
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

You can also directly set the attribute with

```
$a->setAttribute("href", "http://google.com");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$e = $dom->createElement('a', 'link text');
$e->setAttribute('href', 'http://google.com');
$dom->appendChild($e);

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```